# Backup /var/lib/docker without the images?

Tags: docker

I want to make a backup of all my containers and volumes, so the easiest way would be to copy `/var/lib/docker` to another location.

However this directory also includes all the images, and I don't want to include them since they all can easily be re-downloaded from public sources.

So how can I copy this directory while excluding the images?